# Access Database closes upon closing Word document following data export

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a database which stores customer job data. This data is also used to print certificates for the customer via export to an existing word document. The database  is quite old and works fine on office 2003. Upon upgrading to latest office 365 I now have an issue whereby after I export the data to Word, I cannot close Word without Access also closing. I then have to re-open Access to continue using the database. Hoping somebody knows how to stop this happening.
The data is exported to Word at the click of a button in a form and the VBA code it runs is listed below. (I did not create the code or the database)
Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub btnPrintCert_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_btnPrintCert_Click
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim RetVal As Double
    Dim txtWordPath As String
    Dim txtDocPath As String
    Dim txtShellCommand As String

    If Me.Dirty Then
        RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
    ' delete temporary table
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tbltemp_cert"
    ' build sql string
    strSQL = "SELECT qryjobs.postal, qryjobs.payload, qryjobs.JobNumberFull, qryjobs.job_said, qryjobs.job_entrydate, qryjobs.job_number, qryjobs.job_description, qryjobs.job_required_by, qryjobs.job_client_ordernumber, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.job_complete_date, qryjobs.job_completed, qryjobs.cert_owner, qryjobs.cert_address, qryjobs.cert_vehicleyear, qryjobs.cert_vehiclemake, qryjobs.cert_vehiclemodel, qryjobs.cert_chassis, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.cert_vin, qryjobs.cert_rego, qryjobs.cert_axles, qryjobs.cert_application, qryjobs.cert_hubo, qryjobs.cert_huboserial, qryjobs.cert_readingdate, qryjobs.cert_hubo_expiry_km, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.cert_fleetnumber, qryjobs.cert_tare, qryjobs.cert_GVM, qryjobs.cert_GCM, qryjobs.cert_period, qryjobs.cert_expires, qryjobs.cert_MTM_braked, qryjobs.cert_MTM_unbraked, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.cert_front_axlerating, qryjobs.cert_rear_axlerating, qryjobs.cert_axle_spacings, qryjobs.cert_VSR_class, qryjobs.company, qryjobs.addr1line1, qryjobs.addr1line2, qryjobs.addr1line3, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.addr1line4, qryjobs.addr1city, qryjobs.addr1state, qryjobs.addr1postcode, qryjobs.addr2line1, qryjobs.addr2line2, qryjobs.addr2line3, qryjobs.addr2line4, qryjobs.addr2city, qryjobs.addr2state, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.addr2postcode, qryjobs.phone1, qryjobs.phone2, qryjobs.fax, qryjobs.identifier, qryjobs.salutation, qryjobs.contactname, qryjobs.notes, qryjobs.company_type, qryjobs.job_type_desc, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.job_type_code, qryjobs.job_type_LTSA_appr_code, qryjobs.job_type_designcode, qryjobs.job_type_cert_text, qryjobs.job_cert_word_doc, qryjobs.job_type2_desc, qryjobs.job_type2_code, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.job_type2_title, qryjobs.VSR_class, qryjobs.VSR_class_description, qryjobs.axle_description, qryjobs.vehicle_make, qryjobs.application_description, qryjobs.expired_now, qryjobs.cert_vertical_rating, qryjobs.vert_rating, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "qryjobs.qrywelders_all.Name, qryjobs.qrywelders_all.Employer, qryjobs.qrywelders_all.[4711No], qryjobs.qrywelders_all.Positions, qryjobs.qrywelders_all.Expires "
    strSQL = strSQL & "INTO tbltemp_cert FROM qryjobs WHERE [qryjobs.job_said] =" & Me!job_said & ";"

    ' write current record info to temp table
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    ' open & display selected word document according to job type
    ' the Shell function runs an executable program and returns a
    ' Variant (Double) representing the program's task ID if successful,
    ' otherwise it returns zero.
    txtWordPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Winword.exe"
    txtDocPath = Me![job_cert_word_doc]
    txtShellCommand = Chr(34) & txtWordPath & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & txtDocPath & Chr(34)
    Debug.Print "shellcommand: " & txtShellCommand
    RetVal = Shell(txtShellCommand, 1)

Exit_btnPrintCert_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_btnPrintCert_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_btnPrintCert_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing the RetVal and simply using `Shell txtShellCOmmand` I think the requirement for a returned value from the application is probably causing your issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Shell` instead of `CreateObject`, followed by `Documents.Open` to open the file? Then you also wouldn't need to store the exact path to WinWord.exe.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have implemented your suggestions but unfortunately it did not solve my issue. On further investigation it seems the table tbltemp_cert remains bound to the created word document as long as the document remains open. This prevents me from creating further certificates. Yet I cannot close or save the document without Access closing. Very strange. Thanks again.